# How to define a function in scala for flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

New to Scala, I want to try to rewrite some code in flatMap by calling a function instead of writing the whole process inside "()".

The original code is like:

```
val longForm = summary.flatMap(row => {
   /*This is the code I want to replace with a function*/
   val metric = row.getString(0)
   (1 until row.size).map{i=>
     (metric,schema(i).name,row.getString(i).toDouble)
    })
}/*End of function*/)
```

The function I wrote is:

```
def tfunc(line:Row):List[Any] ={
     val metric = line.getString(0)
     var res = List[Any] 
     for (i<- 1 to line.size){
       /*Save each iteration result as a List[tuple], then append to the res List.*/
      val tup = (metric,schema(i).name,line.getString(i).toDouble)
      val tempList = List(tup)
      res = res :: tempList
      }
     res
    }
```

The function did not passed compilation with the following error:

*error: missing argument list for method apply in object List
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
       var res = List[Any]*

What is wrong with this function? 
And for flatMap, is it the write way to return the result as a List?

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried to achieve there by repeatedly prepending to a single-element `tempList`? Regardless of the error message, it doesn't seem quite right. It's also not quite clear what you mean by "user defined function" - there is just your method, no `udf`s?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I'm quite new to spark and scala world. So please bear with me if I wrote anything unclear. My intention was to repalce the long code inside flatMap with a single function. But obviously the function I wrote had compilation issue which I'm not sure which part went wrong. And my second question is how should I replace the original code with a function. Does flatMap pass in a Row Object and the return type is anticipated to be a List of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained *why* you want to replace that code block. Is there a particular goal you're after? There are many, many, different ways that block could be rewritten. How can we know which would be better at meeting you requirements?

Here's one approach.

```
def tfunc(line :Row) :List[(String,String,Double)] ={
  val metric = line.getString(0)
  List.tabulate(line.tail.length){ idx =>
    (metric, schema(idx+1).name, line.getString(idx+1).toDouble)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jwvh. I am on my way learning Scala and Spark, so the reason I want to replace the code is purely learning and curiosity purpose.  Thank you very much for your help.